# Отправка int массива методом POST

Tags: android, post

Добрый день. Я использую `AsyncTask` и методом `POST` отправляю пару `HashMap<String, String>` на сервер без проблем, но как быть с массивом `int[]`?  Как правильно отправлять массив?

Answer (score 4):

Думаю вам поможет Json

```
List<Integer> productIds = ...
JSONArray x = new JSONArray();
for(Integer productId : productIds){
    x.put(productId);
}
```

или, если `int[]`

```
JSONArray x = new JSONArray();
for(int k=0; k < size; k++){
    x.put(productId[k]);
}
```

потом отправляем на сервер. Есть много методов, один вариант

```
 try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://somepostaddress.com";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("intlist", x.toString()));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ну и на сервере можно его потом обратно на массив перевести

```
$list = $_POST['intlist'];

$obj = json_decode($list);
```